# Google Maps API request

Tags: java, xml, web-services, google-maps, xpath

Im doing a project where i wish to send a request to google maps. i need to receive from google a path from one location to another.
This goes in the Web Services area..

It must be done in java.

From what i read at the google maps api description the google response to any request is in XML format.

There's no problem there because for that we can use XPath and any other tool to do the parsing.

So what i need is only how can i send this request to the google API in java? 
If you could explain each step it would be great..

Thank you for your pacience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm working on a simular project (using Mapquest instead of Google). I just used a HttpConnection like this:

```
String requestString = buildURL("Washington", "New York");
URL url = new URL(requestString);
HttpsConnection conn = (HttpsConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
```

Just use the normal request url that the API provides you. Build the URL with parameters like origin and destination using a StringBuilder e.g.

```
public String buildURL(String origin, String destination)
{
StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
urlBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?");
urlBuilder("origin=");
urlBuilder(origin);

urlBuilder("&destination=");
urlBuilder(destination);

urlBuilder("&key=");
urlBuilder(MY_KEY);

return urlBuilder.toString();
}
```

Last step is passing the stream to your XMLParser.
You could also do a response code check on your Connection to handle errors like bad request.